# Is it safe to implement public Search API using Apache Solr

Tags: rest, solr, public

I am looking into ways to make a public REST API implementing (field search / read functionality) available for a website that already implements an Apache Solr search HTTP pages doing similar things.

It occurs to me that one way of doing this would be to just expose the existing Solr REST API directly on the public site, but I am concerned that doing this would be a security vulnerability and/or have other bad effects.

Is there a better way, such as a Solr wrapper?

update: Is there perhaps a prepackaged solution, such as a NodeJS config or Ruby app?

Comment: I'm guessing that Solr has api endpoints to remove data and indexes; exposing those will have "negative side-effects"...

Comment: As long as you don't expose anything that manipulates your index.